Decomposing central simple algebras
Assume $A$ is a central simple algebra of degree $2^nl$ for some odd number $l$ and of index $2^m$ with $m$ dividing $n$.
Question: Can we write $A$ as $B \otimes C$, with $C$ being a central simple algebra of degree $l$ ?
Or in other phrases: "Can we split off the odd part, if the index is even?"

In fact, we have a primary decomposition theorem.
If the degree of $A$ is $p_1^{n_1}\cdots p_r^{n_r}$ where $p_i$ is prime and $n_i\geq 1$, then there exist central simple algebras $A_1,\ldots,A_r$, uniquely determined up to isomorphism, such that $\deg(A_i)=p_i^{n_i}$ for all $i$ and $A\simeq A_1\otimes\cdots \otimes A_r$.
This classical result should be found in any book on c.s.a. It is probably in Albert's book, even if there should be more modern references too.

So, in the case sketched above, the csa with odd degree is necessarily split, right? I mean otherwise the index of $A$wouldnt be a power of $2$, which known to be false. Thanks.
